# Strip out extra spaces when there is more than one in a row

Tags: c#, regex

I am after a Regex expression that will strip out white spaces when there is two or more repeated, leaving just one space behind.

For example this line

```
The cow  jumped    over the moon
```

which has multiple spaces separating the words in some cases would become

```
The cow jumped over the moon
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
[ ]+
```

and replace it with a single space.

Comment: \s would be a better representation.

Comment: Ah, you’re right. Appearently I skipped the “white” in “white space” and just read “space”.

Answer (score 15):

```
string cleanedString = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do it is repeatedly replace two spaces with one until no more entries found. This of course means multiple passes and several rounds of replacements w/ each round allocating and garbage-collecting a string, but I found the overhead to be quite less than parsing and executing a regex. Even with 64 spaces it only takes 7 passes to fix. Besides, typical strings only have 2-5 spaces so it works even faster.

Comment: I can't believe this is faster under any circumstances where you could keep a static regex, and it's certainly less flexible

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time with sed.

```
$ echo "The cow  jumped    over the moon" | sed -e 's/[     ]\+/ /g'
The cow jumped over the moon
```

In the character-class square brackets you have a space and a tab character.  I quoted the '+' with '\', which may not be necessary if your regex engine takes '+' to mean "one-or-more" rather than a literal '+'.